# Azure B2C - Assertion not signed. Policy requires signed assertions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Looking for some help with custom policies on Azure B2C tentant.  I've followed  the steps on this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp

I'm getting a SAML response but its not valid it seems.  I've setup application insights and I see this message in the request **"Assertion not signed. Policy requires signed assertions"**

My baseframework.xml file has this property set to false.  Any other thoughts why I'd be getting this error?

```
    <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between signing and encryption.

You probably want "WantsSignedAssertions".

Comment: Thanks!  Should this be a concern if they're not signing assertions in their response to me?  wondering if I need to bring this up to my client to have them adjust or not.

Comment: It's a security thing. Remember traffic is already https. If it was banking data, you'd expect it to be signed - maybe even encrypted. If it's just an e.g.  "is there a seat available?" flow, then doesn't have to be.